# Jasmine testing JavaScript code against specific HTML

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I am attempting to write unit tests for the following function using Jasmine:

```
function toggleDisplay(divIdToShowHide, showHide) {
var divToShowHide = document.getElementById(divIdToShowHide);
if (showHide == "show")
    divToShowHide.style.display = "block";
else if (showHide == "hide")
    divToShowHide.style.display = "none";
else
    divToShowHide.style.display = (divToShowHide.style.display == "block") ? "none" : "block";
var buttonForDiv = document.getElementById(divIdToShowHide + 'Button');
if (divToShowHide.style.display == "block")
    buttonForDiv.innerHTML = "-";
else
    buttonForDiv.innerHTML = "+";
}
```

I need to test this against a sample HTML code I have written containing various butttons. I am lost on how to get the jasmine tests for the code to actually run on the HTML(since it needs to getElementById). Is there a simple way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look in [Jasmine Jquery](https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery) , it allows you to create tests against specific HTML, so you can see if your javascript is working or not.

Using Jasmine jquery, you can create a [html fixture](https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery#html-fixtures)(just a real or generated html page), and then use their provided jquery-based methods to can check and see if your javascript did what it was supposed to do.